# Format date based on locale in python

Tags: python, time, formatting, locale

I have a date output like

```
>>> import time
>>> print time.strftime("%d %B")
19 July
```

Is there a way to format the date based on the locale, but still have control of what is shown (in some cases I don't want the year).

For example, on a en_US machine, I want it to output:

```
July 19'th
```

Comment: well, it's either based on locale settings or it's not.

Comment: so, what you say is that I have to make an if/else, check in there what locale is currently set, and apply the appropriate formatting ?

Comment: wow. so you want to use the user's settings but not use them?   :-) You could read the locale settings, search for the year and zap that part.  I think that's going to be painful. Why not just have some user preference file where you store the date and let the user spec what they want?

Comment: I know that my solution is wrong, that's why I asked for the right solution. The number of locale is limited to a maximum of 3 - 4, so an else if is not such a big problem, but I wanted it to be scalable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The strftime methods always use the current locale. For example:

```
from datetime import date
d = date.today()
print d.format("%B %d")
```

will output "July 19" (no "'th", sorry...) if your locale is en_US, but "juillet 19" if the locale uses French.

If you want to make the order of the different parts also dependent on the locale, or other more advanced things, I suggest you have a look at the [babel](http://babel.edgewall.org/wiki/Documentation/dates.html) library, which uses data from the Common Locale Data Repository and allows you to do things like:

```
from babel.dates import dateformat
format_date(d, format="long", locale="en_US")
```

which would output "July 19, 2010", but "19 juillet 2010" for French, etc... Note that you have to explicitly request a specific locale though (or rather the language code)
Alas, this doesn't allow leaving off the year. If you delve further into babel however, there are ways to get the patterns for a specific locale (`babel.dates.get_date_format("long", locale="en_US").pattern` would give you "EEEE, MMMM d, yyyy" for example, which you could use for the `format` argument instead of "long"). This still leaves you with the task of stripping "yyyy" out of the format, along with the comma's etc... that might come before or after. Other than that, I'm afraid you would have to make your own patterns for each locale.